# Oracle Error ORA-04093, unable reference long data type

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I am trying to create a trigger on addcomments table, which contains a long coloumn

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER careventCommentssysc
AFTER INSERT 
ON addcomments
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
        cargetcomments(:NEW.addcode, :NEW.addcomment,  'INSERTING');
END careventCommentssysc;
```

when i try to compile this i am getting following error.

```
ORA-04093, references to column of type LONG are not allowed in triggers.
```

But i cant change the table column type to other than long.

Please help me if anyone handled this problem earlier.

Comment: :We cannot refer long data type in Oracle Trigger,so You can change the data type of the column to CLOB

Comment: I found a work around ,but its better to convert the column to CLOB rather than implementing this .Pls find the link `https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3260953`

Comment: @GauravSoni, I have tried this. But i am getting exception ora-02109  (Connection description for remote database not found)

Comment: : Fill the Host,Port ,SID  `CREATE DATABASE LINK LOOPBACK
 USING '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS =(COMMUNITY = world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = 10.176.13.21)(Port = 1547))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = isld)(SERVER = DEDICATED)))'`

Comment: @gauravSoni , Please let me if this haves any disadvantages, or chances of failure

Comment: :I don't think fetching the new value using loopback DB link will lead to failure .But again i am saying using LONG column is depricated in favour of `LOBs` for many Oracle versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:***I think this can be done with Simple compund trigger ,as you are using `ORACLE 11g`,hence this will work for you.No need for any loopback dblinks.Cheers*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER careventCommentssysc FOR
   INSERT
   ON t
   COMPOUND TRIGGER
   l_new_long        LONG;

   TYPE addcomment_nt
   IS
      TABLE OF addcomments%ROWTYPE
         INDEX BY SIMPLE_INTEGER;

   v_addcomment_nt   user_id_nt;
   idx               SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;
   -- AFTER EACH ROW Section:

   AFTER EACH ROW
   IS
   BEGIN
      idx := idx + 1;
      v_addcomment_nt (idx).addcode := :NEW.addcode;
   END
   AFTER EACH ROW;

   -- AFTER STATEMENT Section:

   AFTER STATEMENT
   IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN v_addcomment_nt.FIRST .. v_addcomment_nt.LAST
      LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select addcomment 
                            from addcomments 
                            where addcode = :1'
            INTO   l_new_long
            USING v_addcomment_nt (i).addcode;


         cargetcomments (v_addcomment_nt (i).addcode,
                         :l_new_long,
                         'INSERTING');
      END LOOP;
   END
   AFTER STATEMENT;

END careventCommentssysc;
```

Comment: @maddy:Now see a very simple solution to achieve this .No need for any looback dblink or any hardcoded database name.I am using a Compound trigger to achieve this